# On Windows how do I run a program in the background of a shell, with the ability to close the shell while leaving the program running?

Tags: android, linux, shell, command-line-arguments, nohup

I am using Windows terminal to open up an android emulator. (`emulator -avd <avd_name>`).

But when I close the terminal it kills the emulator too. 
The solution seems to be straight forward in linux. 
But I need it for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
START `my command`
```

Works on batch files too.([Doc here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx))